# Getting back null model after post

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

It seems like a lot of people have this issue, but I haven't found a solution to my specific case yet.

I start by sending my tickets to my view

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddPopcorn()
    {
        List<Ticket> tickets = new List<Ticket>();
        // Fill the list with tickets
        return View("AddPopcorn", tickets);
    }
```

In the view I display the tickets with a form and checkbox. The view displays the tickets correctly.

```
@model List<Domain.Entities.Ticket>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddPopcorn";
}

<body>
  // Html stuff
        @using (Html.BeginForm("AddPopcorn", "Ticket", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <table>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TicketID)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TicketType)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Popcorn)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                }
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Voeg toe!" />
        }
    </div>
</body>
```

If people check the checkbox, I want the value 'Popcorn' to be true. So I want the view to return a list of tickets with updated values for popcorn based on the checkbox.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddPopcorn(List<Ticket> model)
    {
        foreach (var item in model)
        {
            if (item.Popcorn == true)
            {
                item.Price = item.Price + 5;
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Payment", "Payment");
    }
```

However, the model returned to AddPopcorn is null. I can't seem to figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `foreach` loop to a `for`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
  <tr>
    <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model[i].TicketID)
    </td>

    <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model[i].Price)
    </td>

    // etc 

    <td>
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model[i].Popcorn)
    </td>        
  </tr>   
}
```

The default model binder uses a specific convention to work out how to bind a list of items, such as `Model[0].Popcorn` (name). You could check if the HTML for the CheckBox has a `name` attribute set to that format.

Other than using `for`, you could also specify a custom `EditorTemplate` for your `Ticket` object.

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Comment: If this has worked for you, I'd appreciate it if you could accept this as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your form isn't actually posting any data back to the controller.

You need input elements to actually be able to retrieve data from the form.

Instead, on the controller, access the model this way:

```
var model = this.Model
```

The form will **only** send data that you've got in input tags, e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" />
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it send all the data that was send to the view back? I've fixed it now by updating my list from my previous model with tempdata,             List<Ticket> ticketList = (List<Ticket>)TempData["Tickets"];
But that is not the prettiest solutions.